# Connecting streams in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib3

1. I have python3.3
2. I have a Response object from urllib3 (which has a `stream()` method, which returns generator)
3. I have a file I want to write the data to

What is the most idiomatic way of writing data from (1) into (2)? I can use list comprehension to do something like:

```
with http.request_encode_url('GET', …, {'param1': value1}) as response:
    with open(path, 'wb') as fp:
        [fp.write(piece) for piece in response.stream(decode_content=True)]
```

but it just looks too manual for such a common operation

Comment: One not-yet-documented feature is that urllib3 supports the `io` module's interface, which might be helpful for this. (Related docs/PR: https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/pull/432) — I'd write up a full answer but I must run. :) Will check back when I'm back.

Comment: thanks @shazow. the final solution is below. I wonder if similar example would be useful for your documentation

Comment: Absolutely! Please send a pull request. We love documentation contributions. :) We could make a recipes section in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper solution looks like this (thanks for the hint, @Blackjack):

```
from shutil import copyfileobj
from urllib3 import HTTPConnectionPool

_http = HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.example.org', port=80)

response = _http.request_encode_url(
    'GET', 'http://www.example.org/',
    {'param1': value1},
    preload_content=False, decode_content=True
)

with open('output.html', 'wb') as fp:
    copyfileobj(response, fp)
```

Warning: `preload_content=False` is important. otherwise, response would return empty byte-string

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension is not idiomatic because those are meant to produce lists. Meaningful ones. Not ones that are never used and just created for side effects.

Simply use the `writelines()` method of file objects:

```
with http.request_encode_url('GET', …, {'param1': value1}) as response:
    with open(path, 'wb') as fp:
        fp.writelines(response.stream(decode_content=True))
```

Comment: Thanks. It should work for this specific case. I still hope there is a generic solution for "piping" readable stream into writable stream

Comment: @JimiDini As you don't have a readable stream here I don't see how to solve this better than this. If you have an object with a `read()` method and one with a `write()` method there is something in the `shutil` module to ”pump” the data from source to target.

Comment: but `response` is readable! @BlackJack thank you. it looks exactly like what I was looking for. though, `shutil` is a weird place to put it, imho. I'd expect to have it in `io`.